# Order Mobile Buttons Navbar at bottom from left to right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I like to create a navbar at the bottom with bootstrap with big buttons.
So I've set the navbar to fixed-bottom, which works fine, but the Listitems are ordered from top to bottom, but I like an order from left to right.
How can I accomplish that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You could try using: <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it already, but it does not change the behaviour. Now I have removed list and simply added the items without this list item tags, which works.